# Java generic, use methods of original class

Tags: java, generics

What I want to do is, create a function that returns a String with generic arguments. Then I need to use a method getName() that is for the specific class (better explain with the code).

Here is the code:

```
protected StringBuilder createJSON(Collection<E> jsonData) {
        StringBuilder JSONBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        JSONBuilder.append("{\"options\":[");
        int count = jsonData.size();
        for(Object obj: jsonData) {
            count--;
            JSONBuilder.append("{\"label\":\"" + obj.getName() + "\",\"value\":\"" + obj.getName() + "\"}");
            if(count>0) {
                JSONBuilder.append(",");
            }
        }
        JSONBuilder.append("]}");

        return JSONBuilder;
    }
```

createJSON takes a generic collection of objects, the problem is when I need to use getName(). the object that I pass to this function are com.opensymphony.user.UserManager and com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager, both with getName() method.

Comment: ... So what exactly **is** the problem? What doesn't happen that should, or what happens that shouldn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the problem is when I need to use
>   getName(). the object that I pass to
>   this function are
>   com.opensymphony.user.UserManager and
>   com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager,
>   both with getName() method.

You want [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Java doesn't have it. You're out of luck.

Since presumably those classes don't implement an interface with the method you need and you can't change them, your options are:

- Come up with some overengineeded design pattern
- Pragmatically forget about clean OO design and just use `instanceof`

Answer (score 2):

These two objects don't implement the same interface that declares `getName()` method. You'll have to cast the object to one of these two classes and invoke the method or use reflection.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve this with generics is to add an interface which defines `getName()` to all classes which can appear in the collection and then use `Collection<E extends IFace>` (where `IFace` is the name of your new interface).

From the names you specify, I'm pretty sure that you can't retrofit an interface to both.

Which leaves you with a wrapper class: You must wrap your elements in two helper classes which implements the interface and delegates the call to `getName()` to the real class (see adapter or delegate pattern).

Answer (score 2):

You can call method of object only if class/interface of reference to it declares the method. In your case you have to either:

1. cast to ComponentManager or UserManager and then call getName()
2. define your own `interface Nameable {
       public String getName();
   }` Make both classes to implement this interface.
   Now argument of your method will be `Collection<E extends Nameable> jsonData`, so you will be able to invoke this method without casting.
3. Use reflection :(